# How to re-direct front end SEO URLs?

Tags: 301-redirect

Is it possible to 301 re-direct SEO URLs?

For example, www.mywebsite.com/shop/interior
In an e-commerce situation, you can change the URLs for SEO friendly.

Setting up a 301 redirect in the CPanel, it's actually looking for the /shop/interior directory in my FTP, which doesn't exist. Therefore the re-direct is failing.

What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to know how to create SEO friendly URL using .htaccess.

Let's say if the URL format is like:
example.com/shop/product.php?id=xyz

So, in this situation, you need to create SEO friendly URL using .htaccess like:
example.com/shop/product-name

Once this is done then you can set 301 redirects in the original URL

Comment: Hi, I already have the SEO URL's created and working. So you are saying I need to find the original URL and redirect this?

Comment: If you had old URLs and which were not SEO friendly and then you created SEO friendly ones then you need to redirect old URLs to respective new URLs to ensure Google understands this so that ranking can be maintained.